# Backbone parsing json response

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js, nested

I've been using Backbone for a total of 3 days now, and I can see that this has been asked about quite a lot, but honestly I'm just not getting it. I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get a basic app running parsing nested json and I just can't seem to work it out. It all works if I flatten out the json response, and remove the nested elements, but that's not how I will receive it.

I've tried some examples with Backbone relational, but I'm really stuck here, a total backbone n00b, and hoping for some help.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div id="employee-data">
    <script type="text/template" id="employees-template">
        <ol id="data-block">
        </ol>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="employee-template">
        <h2>Your employer: <span><%= employerName %></span> </h2>
        <div>Employee Id: <span><%= employeeId %> </span></div>
        <div>Name: <span><%= employeeName %>     </span></div>
        <div>Title: <span><%= employeeJobTitle %> </span></div>
        <div>Location: <span><%= employeeLocation %> </span></div>
    </script>
</div>
```

**Here is the js:**

```
var Contact = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
   Templates:{}
}

Contact.Models.Employee = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({});

Contact.Collections.Employees = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact.Models.Employee,
    url: "includes/test-data.json",

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Employees initialize");
    }
});

Contact.Templates.employees = _.template($("#employees-template").html());

Contact.Views.Employees = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#employee-data"),
    template: Contact.Templates.employees,

    initialize: function () {       
       this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
       this.collection.bind("add", this.addOne, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log("render")
        console.log(this.collection.length);
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        this.addAll();      
    },

    addAll: function () {
       console.log("addAll")
       this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    },

    addOne: function (model) {
       console.log("addOne")
       view = new Contact.Views.Employee({ model: model });
       $("ol", this.el).append(view.render());
    }

})


Contact.Templates.employee = _.template($("#employee-template").html());

Contact.Views.Employee = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: Contact.Templates.employee,

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.destroyItem, this);
        this.model.bind('remove', this.removeItem, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) ;


    }
})


Contact.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "defaultRoute"
    },

    defaultRoute: function () {
        console.log("defaultRoute");
        Contact.employees = new Contact.Collections.Employees();

        new Contact.Views.Employees({ collection: Contact.employees }); //Add this line

        Contact.employees.fetch({
        error:function(response, xhr){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(xhr)
        },
        success:function(){
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
        console.log(Contact.employees.length)
    }
})

var appRouter = new Contact.Router();

Backbone.history.start();
```

**And finally the json:**

```
[
    {
  "contactId" : "345345234",
  "employees" : [ {
    "employeeId" : "EE-00000001",
    "employeeName" : "BubbA Ho-tep",
    "employeeLegalFirstName" : "Bubba",
    "employeePrefFirstName" : "",
    "employeeLastName" : "Ho-tep",
    "employeeMaritalStatus" : "Single",
    "employeeBirthYear" : "1942",
    "employeeJobTitle" : "",
    "employmentStatus" : "Active",
    "employmentTerminationDte" : "",
    "employeeReferenceCode" : "EE1",
    "employeeDivision" : "HR",
    "employeeLocation" : "Downtown",
    "employeeEmail" : "bubba.hotep@greatmovies.com",
    "employer" : {
      "employerId" : "ER-00000001",
      "employerName" : "Initech"
    }
  } ]
}
]
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you keep adding suffixes like `employee` and `employment` into the properties? If a property is defined inside `employees` then it must be a property of `employee`. For instance wouldn't it suffice to just say `id` and `name` instead of `employeeId` and `employeeName`? If the context changes you can just add a new object holding these new properties, just like you are doing with `employer`.

Comment: I can see what you're saying about the data format, but I don't have any control over how it is formatted when I receive it after the request - that's just how I get the json back from the web service.

Comment: Setting [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) on your model might be a good idea if you're staying with those attribute names (which is a reasonable thing to do).

Comment: Thanks, I will work that in too.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [parse()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method in your collection :

```
Contact.Collections.Employees = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact.Models.Employee,
    url: "includes/test-data.json",

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Employees initialize");
    },

    parse : function(response){
        return response.employees;  
   }    

});
```

There is one parse() in the MOdel as well as in the Collection, for the same purpose on url() handling.

**EDIT :** 
I'm not an expert in the Router, but I suppose you have to render the View at some point.

```
var view = new Contact.Views.Employees({ collection: Contact.employees }); 
view.render();
```

Comment: Okay. That gets me passed the console error, but I'm not seeing how to hook this up to the template to show the data in the page, and the render function down in the Contact.Views.Employees view....

Comment: Do you have your employee in the collection.models when you debug it ?

Comment: I have edited the response for rendering the view ; It's my personal opinion, but I would prefer to add the `View` suffix the any view : `Contact.Views.EmployeesView` is more readable.

Comment: If I'm understanding your edit, adding that view render to the router.... I get the same results as before, but now I get it twice. But still nothing getting to the template in the page. I'm not sure what you mean about having my employee in the collection though. I think it is? Since if I flatten the json I can successfully send data to the underscore template in the page.

Answer (score 0):

model comes with parse method , so when ever you   are making mode.fetch() request , the  output can be parse in model itself

example :

model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot:"/category/",
    parse : function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
}
})

var Model = new model({})