# Backbone make a collection from specific Json attribute

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js, collections

I'm having troubles to understand how Backbone collections mapping external json files...If you have a kind of json and you only work to create models from an specific atribute of that json, how did you do that?

```
            var Comic = Backbone.Model.extend();
            var ComicCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: 'http://www.theurlofthejson.com',
            parse: function (response) {
                  return response.comicsbooks;
                  },
            model: Comic,
           });
```

If then I create a collection

```
var comicCollection = new ComicsCollection();
```

if a make this

```
console.log(comicCollection.fetch())
```

It returns me the entire json not parsed at the comicsbooks level

Why do I get the entire structure of the json object and not only my comicbooks attribute?

My question is based on this one but the implementation/solution don't work for me
[Parsing json backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257722/backbone-parsing-json-response)

Sorry, I miss a sample of the json response of the url attached:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 1,
    "count_total": 4,
    "pages": 4,
    "comicsbooks": [
        {
            "id": 363,
            "type": "american_comics",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "Popeye"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parse` method is wrong. It looks like you're overriding your `Comic` model variable. If you only want the `comicbooks` property to make up your collection do:

```
parse: function(response){
    return response.comicbooks;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I override the Comic model, but this works for me(aparently).

The fact is that is not a good solution because I need to create a model and then override it...wich is the proper way to tell a collection that she has to map only an attribute of json response?

Comment: That may well work for you but it doesn't make sense to do this. Why are you assigning `response.comicbooks` to `Comic`? `Comic` is a backbone model, `response.comicbooks` is raw JSON that you want to inject into your collection, which you do by simply returning `response.comicbooks`. Backbone will take care of the rest, like creating models in your collection from each object in the `comicbooks` array in the server response.

Comment: The fact is that, the last thing you comment _" Backbone will take care of the rest, like creating models in your collection from each object in the comicbooks array in the server response"_...
I really don't understand how backbone works with a json file, how do you tell it that you only want to construct Comic models from an atribute from a JSON file..I mean how do you tell that you don't need all the others attributes?